# ASP.NET, MVC, C# application - modify _Layout.cshtml for different Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET, MVC, C# application that uses the _Layout.cshtml file.
I would like to use the _Layout.cshtml file for multiple Views, but depending on which view is being displayed, I would like to alter the _Layout.cshtml a little.

Such as in _Layout.cshtml have something like -

```
<div>I would like to say </div>

@if(View = "View1")
{
      <div>Hello!</div>
}
@else 
{
      <div>Goodbye!</div>
}
<div>Have a great day!</div>
```

Can someone tell me how this can be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to change more than just a simple text, you could use sections for that. For example, put this in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@RenderSection("mySection", required: true)
```

and in each of your View then:

```
@section mySection
{
    <div>Hello!</div>
}
```

Here's a nice [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you wanted to check the against the action rather than views.  You would want to do something like this

```
@if(Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] == "Home" && Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] == "Index") {
     <div>Hello!</div>
}else {
     <div>Goodbye!</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ingenious solution: in the view add a variable to the ViewBag.
Like so:

```
@ViewBag.Foo="bar"
```

Before you define which view is rendered. And make an if in the layout based on it.

Though this is not the best practice approach - I personally would go for different layouts perhaps.